# python add rows at interval and combine them as one

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have a data set like this

[image]

It is from a logger that logs data every 5 secs. I want to get minute data from it using Python. Is there a way I can merge and add every 12 data points to create minutes of data?

thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably better ways, but this should work.

```
# example df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([1000, 3]), 
columns=('a', 'b', 'c'))

# shorten df so len is divisible by 12 segments
segs = 12
df = df[: (len(df) // segs) * segs]

# add a minute col
df['mins'] = np.array([[i for j in 
range(segs)] for i in 
range(len(df)//segs)]).flatten()

#aggregate
print(df.groupby(['mins'])['a', 'b', 
'c'].sum())
```